# Error when importing south with django after install

Tags: django, django-south

This is my first time using Django and South.

I installed South V1.01 with pip, but when I run 
    manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial

I get

```
File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",     
line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", 
line 354, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in 
populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 87, in   
create module = import_module(entry)
File     
     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module __import__(name)
```

I have added myapp under INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and I can see South installed correctly.

I would appreciate if anyone can tell my where to look for the fix.

Comment: Please do not install Django over system Python, as this may cause issues. Instead, use virtualenv to install Python packages. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#virtual-environments

Comment: Not to be silly, are you using Django 1.7? If so, just use Django 1.7's migrations and remove south. I believe that there may be a conflict between Django/South. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#what-s-new-in-django-1-7

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did try using native migrations, but kept getting a different error. I'd appreciate if you can look at them.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186667/errors-after-django-1-7-migration-and-reset