# Undo Migrations using Django 1.7

Tags: django, migration

I am currently using Django 1.7, and I created a migration that doesn't worlk (I tried to cast a varchar to an integer). I got a long error message (I don't think the specifics of the message are important, but I can add them in). I changed my model back to what it was before, but now whenever do the migration, I get the same long error. I have had this same problem three or four times before, and each time I deleted every table in the database and started my app all over again. I think I have the same problem as this [person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186667/errors-after-django-1-7-migration-and-reset), but I don't where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have changed back your model, but the migrations are still there.

You need to go into the `migrations` folder inside your app, check for the migration that changes the field to an integer field, and delete that migration.

Comment: I went and deleted the migration from the migrations directory, but I am still getting that error.

Comment: Even if you delete all files except `__init__.py` and rerun makemigrations?

Comment: That's what I did. Not sure what the problem was. I ended up giving up, and created a new database.

Comment: Figured it out. What you said works, I just did something stupid instead.